# I changed the default constructor for my class, but seems compiler still calls the default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I create a class A, and overwrite operator+ and constructor `A(A&&)`, I am wondering if I call

```
A a, b;
A c = a + b;
```

Is my constructor `A(A &&)` called?

I tried some code, but get very confusing results

```
//try2.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
  string s;
  A(A &&a) { s=std::move(a.s); cout<<"A(A &&a) called"<<endl;}
  A() {}
};

A operator+(const A &a, const A &b) {
  A c;
  c.s=a.s+b.s;
  return c;
}

int main() {
  A a,b;
  a.s = "123";
  b.s = "456";
  A c = a+b;
  cout<<c.s<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I used gcc 7.0: `g++ -std=c++1y try2.cpp`

Output is  `123456`, therefore `A(A &&a)` is not called

But then I change

`A(A &&a) = delete;`

Then compiler throws error:

```
try2.cpp: In function ‘A operator+(const A&, const A&)’:
try2.cpp:14:10: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
   return c;
          ^
try2.cpp:7:3: note: declared here
   A(A &&a) = delete;
   ^
try2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
try2.cpp:21:11: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
   A c = a+b;
           ^
try2.cpp:7:3: note: declared here
   A(A &&a) = delete;
```

Constructor `A(A &&a)` is required. But why the previous code did not call it?

Comment: Relevant  [Copy elision question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 1):

[Named Return Value Optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

The compiler realized that, instead of creating an `A` in the scope of `operator+` and moving it out of `operator+` and into `main`, it could (basically) just construct it in `main` and have `operator+` work on the value that's in `main`.

In order for your program to be valid, you need some constructor that lets the value be copied -- but the compiler need not use it, if it realizes it can optimize away some copies / moves.

Comment: Thanks! Seems compiler chose the default constructor. To enforce my customization, need to use `c = std::move(a+b)`

Comment: @XianQian Though almost always there should be no point in enforcing it.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Your move constructor is not being called, because the compiler has the option to construct your object 'c', which is being used inside your operator+ function, straight to the object 'c' at the call site. This is an optional optimization that avoids that extra move (or copy) constructor.

You run into a compilation error when explicitly deleting the move constructor, because this is an optional optimization by the compiler. The compiler is still allowed to call a copy/move constructor if it wants, but by explicitly deleting the move constructor you are also implicitly deleting the copy constructor. This leaves no non-copy elision option for the compiler, so it results in an error.

Comment: In C++17 and later, Copy Elison is no longer optional, it is guaranteed to happen